# Oxyplot Tracker does not work in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tooltip, oxyplot, tracker

I started using oxyplot for wpf a few days ago and it works fine. Now that I'm trying to duplicate the same process in Xamarin I notice that the Tracker (tooltip) does not work In Xamarin.Forms and my code is pretty much the same.

I have tried the following:

- Changing the orientation to landscape, just in case the problem was the size of the plot.
- Try adding  tag, but is not available or maybe I'm missing something in xmal.
- I added  TrackerFormatString = "X={2},\nY={4}" to my lineseries thinking that maybe I needed to specify the tracker.

  I used one of the codes from the example [repo](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/tree/master/Source/Examples/WPF/WpfExamples/Examples), can't remember which to create my View Model:

  ```
  public class MyOxyPlot : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public PlotController CustomPlotController { get; set; }
      private PlotModel _myplotModel;
      public PlotModel MyPlotModel
      {
          get { return _myplotModel; }
          set
          {
              if (_myplotModel != value)
              {
                  _myplotModel = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged("MyPlotModel");
              }
          }
      }

      MyOxyPlot()
      {
          ConfigPlot();
      }

      public void ConfigPlot()
      {
          MyPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
          {
              Title = "X-Axis",
              Position = AxisPosition.Left,
              TickStyle = TickStyle.Outside
          });
          MyPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
          {
              Title = "Y-Axis",
              Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
              TickStyle = TickStyle.Outside
          });
          var ls = new LineSeries
          {
              Title = "Some test plot",
              Color = OxyColors.Black,
              LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
              TrackerFormatString = "X={2},\nY={4}"
          };
          ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
          ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 2));
          ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 3));
          ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 4));
          ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 5));

          CustomPlotController = new PlotController();
          CustomPlotController.UnbindAll();
          CustomPlotController.BindTouchDown(PlotCommands.PointsOnlyTrackTouch);
          MyPlotModel.Series.Add(ls);
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }
  ```

My plot work, but the Tracker (tooltip) will not show up in Xamarin.Forms. The expected result should be the same as wpf, a popup that shows the values of x and y coordinates of the data point that have been touch.

Comment: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/1128